# What to do with very little edit in documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I often encounter very little edit in examples in documentation. But I usually ignore them as I do not know what to do with them.

For example, in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/9465?draftId=9620), the editor changed just a letter which corrects the tense: `places` to `placed`.

Should we approve this edit?

Comment: According to the [blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/07/introducing-stack-overflow-documentation-beta/?cb=1): "Small edits and contributions are encouraged."

Comment: @honk Ow, good point. Thanks. :)